# Solution to LTI system of equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, systems-of-equations

I was wondering if there are any mathematical functions that satisfy both of the following equations:

\begin{align}
\frac{dx_1}{dt} &= x_2\\
\frac{dx_2}{dt} &= -x_1
\end{align}
I know one of the solutions would be:

\begin{align}
x_1 &= \sin(t), \text{ since } \frac{dx_1}{dt} = \cos(t) \\
x_2 &= \cos(t), \text{ since } \frac{dx_2}{dt} = -\sin(t)
\end{align}
Can anyone give any other example that satisfies the two equations? Thank you!

Comment: A system of differential equation is defined by two things: the differential equations themselves and initial conditions, which are missing.

Answer (score 3):

The system is linear, so you can scale.

The system is autonomous, so you can time-shift.